# Primary key range depending on row type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, entity-framework-6

I am using SQL Server together with Entity Framework. I have a table with a few thousands rows.

The client wants to add a new data type to this table. Both types are distinguished by `MainType` column.

The client also wants rows of type A to have PK value up to 1000000 and rows of type B above 1000000.

I was thinking about using an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger, but it would be better not to specify name of every column in trigger body it as they may change.

Is it possible to create a trigger that change primary key column?

I am aware that it might not be the best option to manipulate on PK column. Maybe there is a way to do it on the Entity Framework side?

Comment: I would tell the client this is a bad idea and you shouldn't use keys in that manner.

Comment: Why can't this be introduced at the query level? manipulating PK values is a bad idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for this type of situation is to not have the column autogenerated but have the numbers autogenerated. In this way you can ensure they are unique.  SQL Server (and other platforms) provides for this with sequence objects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?view=sql-server-ver15

In this case you would create two sequence objects with the starting points you describe.  When you need an id of one type you grab it from that sequence and when you need an id of the other type you grab it from that type's sequence generator.

FYI I often see this used where one set of sequences is even numbers (starting at 2) and the other is odd numbers (starting at 1).  But I have also seen the really high 2nd set you describe.

The most common use case is full duplexed replication (where you have two data stores replicated to each other that can get new data).  But your use case can use the same technique.